# gitlab-runner, gitlab and jwilder/nginx-proxy inside docker container pipelines fails on clone

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Having the following setup in a docker-compose.yml, which includes the following services:

- jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
- jwilder/nginx-proxy
- gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
- gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  
  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_letsencrypt
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_EMAIL=my-emamil@email.com
      - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=${PROJECT_NAME}_proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx_vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./nginx_certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
    restart: always
    networks:
      - git

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_proxy
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./containers/nginx_proxy/custom_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom_proxy.conf:ro
      - ./nginx_vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./nginx_certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - git  

  gitlab:
    image: "gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest"
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: ${MAIN_DOMAIN}
    ports:
      - "2215:22"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2215
        external_url 'https://${MAIN_DOMAIN}'
        letsencrypt['enable'] = false
        # letsencrypt['auto_renew'] = true
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
    volumes:
      - "./gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab"
      - "./gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab"
      - "./gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab"
    networks:
      - git

  gitlab-runner:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./gitlab-runner/Dockerfile
    user: root
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_gitlab_runner
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - './config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
    restart: always
    networks:
      - git

networks:
  git:
    name: gitlab-network
```

I'm not able to properly set up `gitlab-runner` with the Docker executor.

Here is my runner setup:

```ini
[[runners]]
  name = "docker deployer"
  url = "http://my-repo.com/"
  clone_url = "http://my-repo.com/"
  id = 30
  token = "yebzRVbEUvPACzYNAqd8"
  token_obtained_at = "2023-06-10T21:47:41Z"
  token_expires_at = "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z

"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "node:18"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

It gets registered properly when I use `gitlab-runner register` without using `https`. The runner is active in the CI settings. Here is my simple CI configuration for testing:

```yaml
image: docker:stable

stages:
  - build

variables:
  GIT_TRACE: "1"
  GIT_CURL_VERBOSE: "1"
  DOCKER_IMAGE: "vendor/component"
  DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: 1.0.0
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone

before_script:
  - docker info

services:
   - name: docker:dind

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
 
  script:
     - docker info
     - docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG .
     - echo "Docker image build completed"
     - docker images
     - echo "Attempting to push Docker image"
```

Every time the pipeline is triggered, at the `clone` step, I face the following error: "connection refused." If I use `git clone` inside GitLab Runner and enter my credentials, I can clone the repository. I even tried with a public repository, but the issue remains the same.

### got it working

here is the relevant part for config.toml

```
[[runners]]
  name = "docker runner in container"
  url = "http://gitlab" //this is my container name
  clone_url = "http://gitlab/" //reference container name on clone
  id = 169
  token = "gzD6_X74sbVVMHYHBuzo"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-06-21T15:06:46Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  network_mode = "git"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/certs/client"]
    network_mode = "git" //this needs to be defined because of docker context
    shm_size = 0
```

and here is the gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376/
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
  DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"
  DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME: "vendor/my-image-name"


services:
  - name: docker:dind
    entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]
    command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]
    alias: docker

before_script:
    - until docker info; do sleep 1; done //this is needed to wait till docker is available
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  image: docker:stable
  hooks:
    pre_get_sources_script:
      - echo "test"

  tags:
    - docker

  script:
    - docker pull $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - docker build --cache-from "$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" -t "$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" -f Dockerfile.prod .
    - docker push "$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
```

Comment: In the runner configuration, the `clone_url` should be the URL to the GitLab instance. Make sure it's correctly set and reachable from the runner. What is the exact error message?

Comment: I still get  `WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed                runner=AKPyWBLn status=couldn't execute POST against https://my-domain/api/v4/jobs/request: Post "https://my-domain/api/v4/jobs/request": dial tcp 172.27.0.4:443: connect: connection refused`even with clone_url

Comment: I would like to try using ssh, but I don't know how to setup with this compose setup

Comment: OK, let's try SSH, then. I have posted an answer to this effect.

Comment: when you say "... If I use `git clone` inside Gitlab Runner..." do you mean the runner host itself? The context in which the clone happens is within the container running for the job (from `docker:stable`). Did you try to connect to your Gitlab instance by simulating this same situation (ie: using `docker run ...`)?

Comment: @istepaniuk, yes I mean I do `docker exec -it container-namespace_gitlab_runner /bin/bash` then I test like `ssh-keyscan my-domain >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: @fefe I believe that then it isn't exactly the same. You are exec-ing into the runner itself but Gitlab spins a separate container to run your job. You could run a job with something like `sleep 1h` in the `pre_clone_script` section, and then exec into that stuck job container to debug the issue. As a side note: From the log entry in your comment, it seems that it's trying to connect to https (on 443). Your runner however seems to be configured for http, not https. Additionally, I never had to specify `clone_url` in my toml, just `url` works fine for my on-prem Gitlab instances.

Comment: @istepaniuk as for now I can clone inside of gitlab-runner via ssh my project, but executing the pipeline throws `error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork`

Comment: @istepaniuk can you give me an example for `pre_clone_script` ?

Comment: @fefe it works just like script or before_script. Soemething like `pre_clone_script: [ "sleep 1h" ]`. Your job should hang and you should be able to see the container running with `docker ps` on the host. Use that container id for your `docker exec`. I wouldn't worry much about ssh, you get a "connection refused" so it's more of a lower level issue (dns, firewall, routes, docker networking?)

Comment: so I done the following, added `hooks:
    pre_get_sources_script:
      - until docker ps; do sleep 1; done` build stage, but in console I get `/bin/bash: line 136: docker: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to try using ssh, but I do not know how to setup with this compose setup

Using SSH to clone repositories can be a more secure and reliable method.
To set this up with your docker-compose configuration, you will need to :

1. **Configure SSH on GitLab Container**: In your `docker-compose.yml` file, you have already mapped the SSH port of the GitLab container to port `2215` on the host machine. This is done with the line `- "2215:22"` under the `gitlab` service. This means that GitLab's SSH server is listening on port `2215` of the host machine.
2. **SSH Key**: You will need to generate an SSH key pair if you have not already. This key pair will be used to authenticate the GitLab Runner with the GitLab server.

   ```bash
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com" -P "" -f ~/.ssh/gitlab
   ```

   This command generates a new SSH key pair.
   I would recommend no passphrase for testing: `-P ""`. And a dedicated file name (`gitlab`)
3. **Add SSH Key to GitLab**: you need to add the public SSH key to your GitLab account. Log into GitLab, go to your avatar `> Settings > SSH Keys`.
   Here, paste the contents of the public key (typically located at `~/.ssh/gitlab.pub`) into the "`Key`" field and click "`Add key`".
4. **Configure GitLab Runner to Use SSH**: Update your GitLab Runner configuration to use SSH. In your Runner's `config.toml`, set the `clone_url` to the SSH URL of your GitLab server. The SSH URL typically looks like `ssh://git@my-domain:2215/`.

   ```ini
   [[runners]]
     ...
     clone_url = "ssh://git@my-domain:2215/"
     ...
   ```
5. **SSH Known Hosts**: GitLab Runner needs to trust the GitLab server as a known host. When you first connect to an SSH server, you are usually prompted to verify the host's fingerprint. Since the runner cannot do this interactively, you need to add GitLab's host key to the runner's known hosts. You can do this by running:

   ```bash
   ssh-keyscan -p 2215 my-domain >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
   ```

   Then, in your runner's `config.toml`, configure the SSH settings:

   ```ini
   [[runners]]
     ...
     [runners.ssh]
       user = "git"
       host = "my-domain"
       port = "2215"
       identity_file = "/path/to/your/private/key"
   ```

Finally, after making these changes, restart the GitLab Runner and GitLab services. You can do this with docker-compose:

```bash
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
```

This should set up your GitLab Runner to use SSH to clone repositories from your GitLab server.
Double-check that your domain (`my-domain`) and ports (`2215`) are correctly configured and accessible.
And make sure the path to your private key in the runner's configuration is correct.

Comment: Hi @VonC,  I really appreciate your Feedback, so I try `ssh-keyscan -p 2215 my-domain >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` inside of gitlab-runner container but I get `write (my-domain): Connection refused` so I still have some issues with networking. I don't know what I have setup wrong in compose

Comment: @fefe Does your GitLab runner runs sshd (the SSH daemon)? `docker exec -it ${CONTAINER_NAME}_gitlab /bin/bash` and `ps aux | grep sshd`

Comment: yes that one works

Comment: @fefe Then try, in the container: `ssh-keyscan -p 22 container-namespace_gitlab >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, with  `container-namespace_gitlab` the service name of the GitLab container within the Docker network.